# Send media by mail javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm trying to send a recorded message by mail, but no mail client or message is opening when send button is clicked even if the function is running,

```
function sendMail(media) {
$('#send').click(function() {
var link = "mailto:me@example.com"
+ "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
+ "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")
+ "&body=" + media
;

window.location.href = link;
 });
```

}

whats the problem in my script?

Answer (score 0):

In your `sendMail` function you create a handler for your button. So you need to call `sendMail();` once after declaration to create a handler. I think there is no point in creating separate function if you're going to use it just once. You should do this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#send').click(function() {
    var link = "mailto:me@example.com"
    + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
    + "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")
    + "&body=" + media;

    window.location.href = link;
  });
});
```

Comment: but were should i put this, i have to send in the varible media to the function, and to do ths i call the sendMail() is started in that function,